# How to avoid casts in concrete implementation of base classes in c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, interface

I'm writing a proof of concept database system where by I'd like to define some base implementation of a database table and rows, and then derive from a base class that represents a table and a row. So, for example I have laid out in my project --

```
public interface ITable
{ 
    void InsertRow(BaseRow row); 
}

public abstract class BaseRow { }
public class ConcreteRowA : BaseRow {}
public class ConcreteRowB : BaseRow {}

public class ConcreteTableA : ITable
{
    public void InsertRow(BaseRow row)
    {
       if (row is ConcreteRowA)
       {
           var RowA = (ConcreteRowA)row;
       }
       // do stuff specific to a RowA type
    }
}

public class ConcreteTableB : ITable
{
    public void InsertRow(BaseRow row)
    {
       if (row is ConcreteRowB)
       {
           var RowB = (ConcreteRowB)row;
       }
       // do stuff specific to a RowB type
    }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid having to do the check and cast for a type in my implementation, so it would be nice if instead --

```
public class ConcreteTableA : ITable
{
    public void InsertRow(ConcreteRowA row)
    {
       // do stuff specific to a RowA type
    }
}

public class ConcreteTableB : ITable
{
    public void InsertRow(ConcreteRowB row)
    {
       // do stuff specific to a RowB type
    }
}
```

But I understand that when I implement an interface that it doesn't work this way. Is that correct, or am I misunderstanding how to use abstract classes and interfaces? Is there a better way to implement what I'm trying to do?

In essence I would like to enforce classes ConcreteTableA and ConcreteTableB the same type of method "InsertRow" but accept a parameter of a type specific to their implementation (ConcreteRowA or ConcreteRowB). Is there a flaw in my design? I feel like I must be violating some principle.

Comment: You could make your tables generic on the row type or have all of your rows to implement an interface (`IRow`) and inject simply the `IRow` to the `InsertRow` method.

Comment: `void InsertRow(BaseRow row);` could perhaps instead be `void InsertRow(T row) where T: BaseRow;` You could perhaps even add the `T` constraint to the class (`ConcreteTableA`) rather than the method.

Comment: In retrospect, that makes total sense. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to declare a concrete instance of a table that uses a particular type of row. This is a good candidate for [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters). You can modify the interface declaration to [enforce a constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) the type of row required;

```
public interface ITable<TRow> where TRow : IRow
{ 
    void InsertRow(TRow row); 
}
```

You can then define;

```
public class ConcreteTableA : ITable<ConcreteRowA>
{
    void InsertRow(ConcreteRowA row); 
}

public class ConcreteRowA : IRow
{

}

public class ConcreteTableB : ITable<ConcreteRowB>
{
    void InsertRow(ConcreteRowB row); 
}

public class ConcreteRowB : IRow
{

}
```

Comment: Ok, this makes total sense. I've read the MSDN page on Generics but to be completely honest I was struggling a bit with understanding it's application. Thank you very much for your answer!